# Run script only on index of url

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a snippet of some script which allows it to run on a URL containing a specific string.

```
if(location.href.indexOf("MODULE=MESSAGE")>0||location.href.indexOf("/message")>0) { //GOOD TO GO
    if(location.href.indexOf("c=0")>0||location.href.indexOf("c=0")>0) chatLinkStyle = " style='display:none'";
```

I need to add a second allowance for the script to run on indexOF("SEQNO")

Here is the URL string for the current allowed pages

```
mysite/2015/55392?MODULE=MESSAGE1
mysite/2015/55392?MODULE=MESSAGE2
mysite/2015/55392?MODULE=MESSAGE3
```

ect.....MESSAGE20

Here is the other URL string i want to allow in addition to the current

```
mysite/2015/options?L=55392&O=247&SEQNO=0
mysite/2015/options?L=55392&O=247&SEQNO=1
mysite/2015/options?L=55392&O=247&SEQNO=2
```

ect...SEQNO=20

No idea how to edit the above to allow for multiple indexOf , any help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add multiple if statements (||)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var myurl = "http://yourwebsite.com/index.php";
var currenturl = window.location;
if(myurl == currenturl) {
    //run your code
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit more cleaner way of doing it. The advantage here is that you can keep adding patterns and don't need to change the code, such as adding another `if` condition etc.

```
var allowedPatterns = [
    "MODULE=MESSAGE",
    "/message",
    "c=0",
    "SEQNO"
],
    href = location.href,
    valid = true;

for (var i=0, j = allowedPatterns.length; i<j; i++) {
    if ( href.indexOf(allowedPatterns[i]) === -1 ) {
        valid = false;
        break;
    }
};

if (valid) {
    //Your code
}
```